# Get/insert value into picklist from database

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i'm newbie in tech JSF so i faced problem in relevent between my app and database the main issus appear when i select one item or more from list instead of saveing selected data, it doesn't insert anything.
i found somes question near to be as mine but no one success in my case because most of them give example for static value while i'm working on dynamic which token from database.
Finally : i need to get the code core for synchornization of value from database!!
here the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5Pk5.png) of my xhtml how its look.
then here my code backbean:

```
public DualListModel<Mission> getMissions() {

    // Players
    teamNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    source = new ArrayList<Mission>();
    target = new ArrayList<Mission>();

    source.addAll(oservice.listMission());

    missions = new DualListModel<Mission>(source, target);
    return missions;

}
```

And this block for xhtml:

```
<h:form>
<p:growl id="msg" showDetail="true" escape="false" />
<p:pickList id="teamPickList" value="#{details.missions}" var="mission" itemValue="#{mission}" itemLabel="#{mission.tache}" showSourceControls="true" showTargetControls="true" showCheckbox="true" responsive="true" showSourceFilter="true" showTargetFilter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" converter="mConverter"> <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Available</f:facet> <f:facet name="targetCaption">Starting</f:facet> <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{details.onTransfer}" update="msg" /> <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{details.onSelect}" update="msg" /> <p:ajax event="unselect" listener="#{details.onUnselect}" update="msg" /> <p:ajax event="reorder" listener="#{details.onReorder}" update="msg" /> <p:column style="width:100%;"> #{mission.tache} </p:column> </p:pickList> </h:form>
```

then here is my converter code:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class PlayerConverter implements Converter {
@EJB
ServiceOffreLocal oservice;


@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {

    return oservice.getMission(Integer.parseInt(submittedValue));


}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object value) {
     return String.valueOf(((Mission) value).getId_Miss());
}
}
```

i can't figure out where is my fault in my trying code!!

Comment: The View does not care where the data comes from, as long as you perform a clear seperation of responsibilies. As does the Logic which is responsible for persisting the data. Which part are you exactly struggeling with? You should try to specify your question ... maybe this does even help you to find the problem by yourself.

Comment: the issue i faced where the target picklist does not persist into database

Comment: Can you show the submit button and its submit function

Comment: `public void afficherTarget(){
  for(Mission m : missions.getTarget()){
   rub.setMission(m);
   oservice.createRubrique(rub);
  }`

Comment: this code of button in xhtml :

`<p:commandButton value="submit" actionListener="#{details.afficherTarget}"/>`

Comment: @HamdiZairi: you can edit your question and put this information in there. More easily readable that way

Comment: So, we have two tables (entites) Mission and Rubrique.
i need to get the list of missions in the picklist source and put the selected items from target picklist into Rubrique 

in the case of source , we haven't any problem and also about the transfer of items between source and target but in the target case , **i don't add the selected items into rubrique table in the database**  .

i hope to resolve my problem and thank you in advance